# I am getting the error .class expected but can not find a solution to change the line! Any ideas?

Tags: java

The method is-

```
private class DisplayNum implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        intInput = String.valueOf(array[]);
        finalArea.setText("\n" + intInput);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is with the `intInput` line, I am getting a .class expected and have been told I need to change the line in general but do not know what to make it.

Comment: Can you accept one of answers, clearly you have used it in asking another post.

Answer (score 0):

intInput should be declared as String.

array should be array or array[0], and it should be fetched from event I guess.

Answer (score 0):

String.valueOf(array[])

doesn't make any sense.

Assuming array is an int[] you would need to specify an index to get a particular value out of, for instance:

```
String intInput = String.valueOf(array[0]);
```